# Ruby on Rails, using activerecord to get all records that have a specified field containing a string in my array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

So i know i can do something like this `Model.Where('field LIKE ?','%mystring%')` to get all records containing my string inside my specified field.

But is there to make it check through an array of strings rather than a single string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do in PostgreSQL:

`Model.where("field ILIKE any (array[?])", ["%mystring1%", "%mystring2%"])`

Comment: I have a problem, i want it so it would retrieve the records that contain the words inside the array as words on their own, not as a substring, is there a way to do this here ?

Comment: I believe that for this sort of accuracy you'd like to introduce something like ransack: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack to your app. If your search options are going to expand - searchkick: https://github.com/ankane/searchkick is even better option.